# Capitilize lines starting with ** in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to **capitalize every line** starting with int.  or INT.

Following command

```
    %s/\<int.*\>/\U&/gi
```

capitalize lines like international, integer too. (I know I can add c and search it then confirm it but I prefer adding that to my .vimrc and having the result whenever I save the file.)

So how can I only capitalize lines starting with int .  (int period space another word(s)..) I tried

```
%s/\<int.\s*\>/\U&/g
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Escape the dot.

Comment: When I escape the dot it capitalizes only the word int but does nothing to rest of the line.

Comment: Are you using `%s/\<int\..*/\U&/gi`?

Comment: oops no without i. :( It worked with i . Thanks

Comment: I am not quite convinced: if `int` must be at the start of a line, you need `%s/^int\..*/\U&/gi`

Comment: it worked actually. Both works. int. is always at the start in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
%s/^int\..*/\U&/i
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `int\.` - a `int.` substring
- `.*` - all text to the end of the line.

The `\U&` replacement turns all the matched text to upper case.

The `i` flag makes matching case insensitive. Note you do not need `g` here as the command will affect all lines, and there is only 1 match per line.

Comment: In my case both %s/\<int\..*/\U&/gi  and %s/^int\..*/\U&/gi worked. Than you for the explanation.

Comment: @ibrahim Your first example will match lines which do not necessarily begin with "int.". It will match any "int." word in the middle of a line up to its end.

Answer (score 3):

I would do with `:g` command:

```
:g/^int\./norm! gUU
```

Some **Notes**:

- the above line works for option `ic` set. I feel it convenient to have `ic` and `scs` set.
- the line below works no matter if you have `ic` set or not:

  ```
  :g/\c^int\./norm! gUU
  ```

Comment: You were a bit faster than me on the `:g` solution. I didn't know `norm!`, I have learnt something, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @kent Works great. I love Vim because there is always more than one way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Just saying: it seems easier to do with `:g`.

Something like:

```
:g/\v^(int|INT)\./norm! gUU
```

- `\v` activates the very-magic mode for regexp, not mandatory but I find it easier this way,
- `:g` takes all the lines matching the pattern, and launches `norm! gUU` for each of those lines *(thanks to @Kent for the tip!)*. As you know, `gUU` in normal mode transforms the whole line to uppercase.

More info about `:g` here : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g
That's easily one killer feature of Vim that many users don't know of. I couldn't live without it!

Comment: Thank you @pierre-adrien-buisson That works very nicely too.